# Asp.Net Core Endpoint routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have an `Action` in a `Controller`:

```
[Route("")]
[Route("{pageNumber?}")]
[Route("tag/{tagSlug?}/{pageNumber?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNumber, string tagSlug = null, string searchTerm = null)
{
    var model = await repoPm_.GetPage(pageNumber, tagSlug, searchTerm);
    return View(model);
}
```

Each item has a list of tags associated with it

```
@foreach (var t in item.Tags)
{
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-tagSlug="@t.TagSlug" class="mr-3">@t.Name</a>
}
```

And in my navbar i have a link to the page, which, I've tried the following:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Index" asp-route-tagSlug="">Items</a>
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Index" asp-route-tagSlug="@null">Items</a>
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Index">Items</a>
```

When I'm not on that page, the link in the navbar points to `/items/tag` which is annoying, but it works.

When I am on that page and I've clicked on one of the tags then the Url in the Omnibar is proper, i.e. `/items/tag/fancy-items`

The problem is that is also the generated url for the link in my navbar, i.e. `/items/tag/fancy-items` when it should be just `/items`

What am i doing wrong? I don't want to get into a bunch of route-mapping in `Startup.cs`, seems like `<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Index">Items</a>` should just work

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloads to separate your different routes such that their URLs are discrete from one another.

This way, calling your `Index` action with no parameters can only ever be reached by `/items`, and the run-time binding behavior of ASP.NET will not incorrectly resolve to a different URL.

My suggestion would be to make the top-level Action calls overloads that resolve to the same underlying method for reusability.

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return await WrappedMethod(null);
}


[Route("tag/{pageNumber}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int pageNumber)
{
    return await WrappedMethod(pageNumber);
}

[Route("tag/{tagSlug}/{pageNumber}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string tagSlug, int? pageNumber)
{
    return await WrappedMethod(pageNumber, tagSlug);
}

private async Task<IActionResult> WrappedMethod(int? pageNumber, string tagSlug = null, string searchTerm = null)
{
    var model = await repoPm_.GetPage(pageNumber, tagSlug, searchTerm);
    return View(model);
}
```

Note that the nullability of the parameters themselves will depend on your use-cases.

Comment: Ach, dunno what happened last night, coulda sworn I tested your code and it worked, but today... nope. When I'm on `/items/tag/fancy-tag`, the link in my nav bar is the same. And the anchor helper tag in my nav bar is `<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Index">Items</a>`